# Mongo DB query equivalent for this PostgreSQL query

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

I have a query in my spring boot app written to fetch some data from PostgreSQL and now I need to change from PostgreSQL to MongoDB so kindly someone please help me with creating this query.

The following is the query I have which I need to converted to MongoDB query.

```sql
Select
  MessageList.msgchannel as name,
  count(*) as received,
  count(*) filter (
    where
      MessageList.routeStatus = 'Processed'
  ) as processed,
  count(*) filter (
    where
      MessageList.routeStatus = 'In-Flight'
  ) as inflight,
  count(*) filter (
    where
      MessageList.routeStatus = 'Failed'
  ) as failed
from
  MessageList
where
  (
    MessageList.timestamp >= :startDate
    AND MessageList.timestamp <= :endDate
  )
group by
  MessageList.msgchannel
order by
  MessageList.msgchannel
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like this should do:

```js
[
  {
    // filter out records you don't want
    $match: {
      $and: [
        { timestamp: { $gt: startDate } },
        { timestamp: { $lt: endDate } },
      ],
    },
  },
  {
    // keep msgchannel + the flags
    $project: {
      msgchannel: 1,
      processed: {
        $cond: { if: { $eq: ["$routeStatus", "Processed"] }, then: 1, else: 0 },
      },
      inflight: {
        $cond: { if: { $eq: ["$routeStatus", "In-Flight"] }, then: 1, else: 0 },
      },
      failed: {
        $cond: { if: { $eq: ["$routeStatus", "Failed"] }, then: 1, else: 0 },
      },
    },
  },
  {
    // group everything to get final result
    $group: {
      _id: "$msgchannel",
      received: { $sum: 1 },
      processed: { $sum: "$processed" },
      inflight: { $sum: "$inflight" },
      failed: { $sum: "$failed" },
    },
  },
];
```